Mongoose, updating a single element in array of numbers
i'm kinda new at develping apps with nodejs and mongoose, i'm trying to update an array of numbers by modifying a single value inside it but i can't find the correct way to do it.
this is the document:
{ 
id:5,
arrayOfValues:[2,3,4,5]
}

Let's say i receive a value of 10 that must be stored in position 1, the desired outcome is:
{ 
id:5,
arrayOfValues:[2,10,4,5]
}

I thought about using model.findOne() and then model.updateOne() but since this operation could be done several times per minute i was searching for a more efficient method.
Edit: This is my current typescript code:
const filter = {'id':receivedMessage.id};
const options = {upsert:true, includeResultMetadata: true};


const foundDocument = await myModel.findOne(filter);

if(foundDocument){
    let tempArray = foundDocument.myArray;
    let position = receivedMessage.k;
    let value = receivedMessage.v

    tempArray[position] = value

    await myModel.updateOne(filter, {myArray: tempArray}, options);
}

What is the correct way to update only that single element of the array?

You can simplify the update operation by directly using Mongoose updateOne method with the $set operator. Here's the simplified version of your update operation, without the need to retrieve the document first:
const filter = { id: receivedMessage.id };
await myModel.updateOne(
  filter,
  { $set: { [`arrayOfValues.${receivedMessage.k}`]: receivedMessage.v } }
);


You can find the official MongoDB documentation for the $set operator here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Thank you this solved my problem, i looked at the documentation before asking the question but couldn't find the solution.
